# Workspace and android-sdk folder missing

Tags: android, windows, eclipse

I recently installed Windows 8 on a separate partition. I launched eclipse and I got the error workspace not available. I don't remember the exact location of my workspace and I haven't been able to find it. Apart from that I can't find my android-sdk folder either. I can't access my other OS on the other partition because I deleted it. I noticed many files were missing. I'm sure I didn't delete them. I only deleted the windows folder. What did I do if in case I actually deleted my workspace and android-sdk? Can anyone recommend file recovering softwares please. I'm sorry I had to post this, but I get the best answers from here!